# How to create multiple sub menu and its database struture?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create dynamic multiple sub menu by admin.
How to create that for example,

```
> products(Main menu) 
>    ->apple(sub menu)
>      ->Mac
>      ->ipod
>            ->ipod 4G
>            ->ipod 5G
>      ->ipad   
>    ->microsoft    
>    ->HP
```

Like this I have to create menus from admin section.How to do that?

Comment: id | name | parent_id < this will be good structure.

Comment: get the "SQL Antipatterns" book and read about *Closure Tables*.

Comment: try to use nested sets (id | name | level | left_key | right_key)

Answer (score 0):

You can create table of pages to menu, then add to it foreign key of itself which is the primary key of its parent. And when you select menu from db you can select all which the same kays and so long, to time when you select all submenus.

so structure from comment `id|name|parent_id` is simpliest, good example of this table.